# How to force Calculator Price Rules to fire after changing something in Configurator?

Tags: cpq

This is my scenario:

I have configuration attribute on Configurator.

There are two options:

- A
- B

When option **A** is selected, the Price on the QuoteLine should be editable.

When option **B** is selected, the Price on the QuoteLine should not be editable.

The problem:

*SBQQ__PriceEditable__c* can be editable only on QuoteLine level, which is available only for **Calculator** evaluation event of Price Rule.

When Price Rule has evaluation event : **Configurator** we can affect only

- Product
- Product Option

So the real question is:

> How to force **Calculator Price Rules** to fire after changing something in **Configurator**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't do this, but the Quote Line is firing Calculate so in QCP we can use

```
export function onAfterCalculate(quote, quoteLines) { 
  line.record["SBQQ__PriceEditable__c"] = true;
}
```

and put our logic there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't adjust most pricing values from the configurator anyway, because it is not dependent on the existence of a quote line at the time of configuration. Move all of your pricing rules (minus quantity edits/etc.) to calculator scope and then you can control this in the way you seek.